# Pass 'this' to a class variable inside constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am interested, how to pass `this` to a class variable inside a constructor of a parent, so I could use parents methods and access other variables of the parent and call their methods?

Here is my parent class:

```
var async = require('async');
var Rater = require('./rater')
var Similars = require('./similars')
var Suggestions = require('./suggestions');

module.exports = class Engine {
    constructor() {
        this.likes = new Rater(this,'likes');
        this.dislikes = new Rater(this,'dislikes');
        this.similars = new Similars(this);
        this.suggestions = new Suggestions(this);
    }
```

And here is the example of usage and where is get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'engine' of undefined
at --\\classes\rater.js:89:19
```

```
module.exports = class Rater {
  constructor(engine,kind) {
    this.type = kind;
    this.engine = engine;
    if(kind == 'likes') //database schemes
      this.db = Likes_db;
    else if(kind == 'dislikes')
      this.db = Dislikes_db;
    else if(kind == 'similars')
      this.db = Similars_db;
    else if(kind == 'suggestions')
      this.db = Suggestions_db;
  }
  //..
  //other methods
  //..
  remove(user,item,done) {
      this.db.remove({user: user,item: item},(err) => {
        if(err)
          return done(err);
        async.series([
          function(done) {
              this.engine.similars.update(user,done); //error-cant enter the method
          },
          function(done) {
            this.engine.suggestions.update(user,done);
          }
        ],function(done) {

        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the property `engine` defined on `Rater`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips inside constructor

Comment: If you check the value of `this` at the start of  the `remove` method, and then again inside the `this.db.remove` block, and finally inside your async `function(done) {` callback, do you find anything interesting?

Hint - there are differences between an arrow function and a function expression, mostly with how `this` is handled.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the constructor. 
The problem appears because you are using a regular function as the callback and the context switches (you get another **this** in there).

Use an arrow function instead to keep the same context.

```js
 async.series([
          (done) => {
              this.engine.similars.update(user,done); //error-cant enter the method
          },
          (done) => {
            this.engine.suggestions.update(user,done);
          }
        ],function(done) {

        });
```

Simply doing this works fine:

```js
class Rather {
  constructor(engine: Engine) {
    engine.method();
  }
}
class Engine {
  constructor() {
    new Rather(this);
  }
  method() {
    console.log('ENgine');
  }
}

new Engine();
```

You can see a working example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Rather%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(engine%3A%20Engine)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20engine.method()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Engine%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Rather(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20method()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('ENgine')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Engine()%3B).

**Note**: As an OOP design decision though this is not very clean, you are introducing a cyclic dependency. Try going injection or at least introduce an interface to separate the 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a _this var and then give it to parameter:

```
module.exports = class Engine {

var _this = this, _constructor = (<any>this).constructor;

    constructor() {
        this.likes = new Rater(_this,'likes');
        this.dislikes = new Rater(_this,'dislikes');
        this.similars = new Similars(_this);
        this.suggestions = new Suggestions(_this);
    }
```